# How can I reduce the number DB calls Django makes when querying child model properties?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-orm

I am having a hard time figuring out basic optimization and would appreciate some insight or somebody pointing me to the right direction.

Simplified models:

```
class TimeStampedModel(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Venue(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200, db_index=True)

class Offer(TimeStampedModel):
    venue_associated = models.ForeignKey(Venue, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=True)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=500, db_index=True)
```

Simplified view:

```
class MapView(ListView):
    fields = ["name"]
    model = Venue
    template_name = "venues/venue_map.html"
```

Simplified template:

```
{% for venue in venue_list %}
    {{ venue.name }}
    {{ venue.offer_set.latest.created }}
    {{ venue.offer_set.latest.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

This creates a huge volume of DB calls (~400). Going through the whole venue_list only creates a single call (+1 not associated) yet the two offer_set calls create new calls (each 200).

Thus I assumed creating a separate property "latest" for the Venue model would help since it would at least deal with doubling of the "latest" call but no. I also tried playing around with overriding the generic ListView methods which didn't get me anywhere.

There is probably a way of doing this that I am not seeing. Currently, all I can think of is just adding additional fields to the Venue model to just duplicate the information and would require additional logic to manage it.

**EDIT:**

I tried:
queryset = Venue.objects.prefetch_related('offer_set')

All it does is create an additional query:

```
SELECT ••• FROM "offers_offer" WHERE "offers_offer"."venue_associated_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200)
```

The same 400 queries of (with different id values) still run:

```
SELECT ••• FROM "offers_offer" WHERE "offers_offer"."venue_associated_id" = 1 ORDER BY "offers_offer"."order" ASC, "offers_offer"."created" DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I think the edit in my answer would help. It's a non-ideal way to accomplish what you're trying, but it'll work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django provides constructs like `select_related` and `prefetch_related` to optimize the related object query operations. In your case, it should be :

```
   queryset = Venue.objects.all().prefetch_related('offer_set')
```

For the latest item, have you tried with adding `ordering` meta value in `Venue` model as follows :

```
class Offer(TimeStampedModel):
    ......

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created']


{% for venue in venue_list %}
    {{ venue.name }}

    {% with venue.offer_set|first as first_offer %}
    {{ first_offer.created }}
    {{ first_offer.content }}
     {% endwith %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Edited my initial question. The latest() still most likely is the part creating new queries. Is there a way around it or a better way to do it?

Comment: Why you are fetching `latest()` ?

Comment: For every venue, I need the most recent offer object for my template.

Comment: @UssiSonad , I have updated my answer above. Please let me know, whether it works or not

Comment: Thanks, edited answer with minor changes solved my whole problem. From 400 to 2 queries. I had to use venue.offer_set.first instead of venue.offer_set|first but it worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: I am glad it helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

Well typically you can fetch all the related models in an extra query, with **`prefetch_related(..)`**, so we can add that to the `queryset` attribute of the `ListView`:

```
class MapView(ListView):
    fields = ["name"]
    model = Venue
    queryset = Venue.objects.prefetch_related('offer_set')
    template_name = "venues/venue_map.html"
```

Comment: Edited my initial question. The latest() still most likely is the part creating new queries. Is there a way around it or a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

you are accessing the relational data, in django if you access the related data with normal query, it will hit db hit again and again. So for this you can use prefetch_related query for the particular relation, which fetech all the db for that table in one go, when you will iterate on that item it will not hit database again. All data will come on one Query.

```
 queryset = Venue.objects.prefetch_related('offer_set')
```

Comment: Edited my initial question. The latest() still most likely is the part creating new queries. Is there a way around it or a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a more granular analysis of what's really going on behind the scenes in **Django** when you make these `Queries` to `Django ORM`.

The `Querysets` are lazy, meaning : (According to [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated))

> Internally, a QuerySet can be constructed, filtered, sliced, and generally passed around without actually hitting the database. No database activity actually occurs until you do something to evaluate the queryset.

`Querysets` can only be evaluated when you perform either of these actions:
`iteration`, `slicing`, `pickling`, `repr()`, `len()`, `list()` or `bool()`

Well, here, if we see the SQL query you're executing :

PS: You can view the SQL query that will hit the database by this piece of logging in your shell:

```
import logging
l = logging.getLogger('django.db.backends')
l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
l.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())

result_queryset = Venue.objects.all()

SELECT "venue"."id"......(all model fields)......FROM "venue";
```

Here, in above SQL query, you won't see any `related fields` objects, other than `id` of `ForeignKeys`.

Now, if you access any related field for the above queryset, ORM will hit the Database again to grab it. This can be prevented by `prefetch_related()` or `select_related()` (Differences between both [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related))

```
result_queryset = Venue.objects.prefetch_related('offer_set')
# Django creates API accessors for the "other" side of the relationship
# Here, _set is used to access that "other" side i.e. related objects

A NEW SQL QUERY THAT FETCHES YOUR offer_set OBJECTS via a JOIN (that is how prefetch_related works)
```

Moreover, everytime your template demands `name`, `offer_set.latest.created`, `offer_set.latest.content`, it'll hit the database because of this lazy evaluation of `Querysets`.

**EDIT:**

As you have edited your question, you want all `Venue` objects as a whole and don't wan't 400 queries to hit your database, I am gonna suggest a non-ideal way to do it-

**Evaluate your queryset beforehand, before passing it as context to template.** I have already mentioned a lot of ways to do that above.

Comment: Since you mentioned evaluation I got somewhat closer thanks to this. Evaluation of the view would've created the need for additional logic in the template as well. Thus I opted for @cached_property decorator and its invalidation in the models. Not an ideal solution but seems cleaner than evaluation in the view / logic in template and killed 200 queries. So progress, thank you.

Comment: glad that it helped :)